# Elasticsearch wildcard query with hyphens and lowercase filter

Tags: search, autocomplete, elasticsearch

I want to do a wildcard query for `QNMZ-1900`

As I read in the docs, and tried by myself, the standard tokenizer of Elasticsearch splits the words on hyphens, for example `QNMZ-1900` will be split to `QNMZ` and `1900`.

To prevent this behavior, I'm using the `not_analyzed` feature.

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test-idx' -d '{
"mappings": {
    "doc": {
        "properties": {
            "foo" : {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
        }
    }
}
}'
```

I'm putting something into my index:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test-idx/doc/1' -d '{"foo": "QNMZ-1900"}'
```

Refreshing it:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test-idx/_refresh'
```

Now I can use a wildcard query and find `QNMZ-1900` :

```
curl 'localhost:9200/test-idx/doc/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
"query": {
     "wildcard" : { "foo" : "QNMZ-19*" }
}
```

My question:

**How I can run a wildcard query with a lowercase search term ?**

I've tried:

```
curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/test-idx'
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test-idx' -d '{
"mappings": {
    "doc": {
        "properties": {
            "foo" : {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
                "filter": "lowercase"
            }
        }
    }
}
}'
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test-idx/doc/1' -d '{"foo": "QNMZ-1900"}'
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test-idx/_refresh'
```

but my lowercase query:

```
curl 'localhost:9200/test-idx/doc/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
"query": {
     "wildcard" : { "foo" : "qnmz-19*" }
}
}'
```

doesn't find anything.

How to fix it ?

Comment: aren't wildcard queries not analyzed by default?

Comment: Is it possible to set the not_analyzed option while running the search query?

Answer (score 8):

One solution is to define a custom analyzer using

- a `keyword` tokenizer (which keeps the input value as it is, as if it was `not_analyzed`)
- a `lowercase` tokenfilter

I've tried this :

```
POST test-idx
{
  "index":{
    "analysis":{
      "analyzer":{
        "lowercase_hyphen":{
          "type":"custom",
          "tokenizer":"keyword",
          "filter":["lowercase"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT test-idx/doc/_mapping
{
  "doc":{
    "properties": {
        "foo" : {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "lowercase_hyphen"
        }
    }      
  }
}

POST test-idx/doc
{
  "foo":"QNMZ-1900"
}
```

As you can see using the _analyze endpoint like this :

```
GET test-idx/_analyze?analyzer=lowercase_hyphen&text=QNMZ-1900
```

outputs only one token lowercased but not split on hyphens  :

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "qnmz-1900",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 9,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 1
      }
   ]
}
```

Then, using the same query :

```
POST test-idx/doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard" : { "foo" : "qnmz-19*" }    
  }
}
```

I have this result, which is what you want:

```
{
   "took": 66,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test-idx",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "wo1yanIjQGmvgfScMg4hyg",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "foo": "QNMZ-1900"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

However, please note that this will allow you to query only using **lowercased value**.
As stated by Andrei in comment, the same query with value `QNMZ-19*` won't return anything.

The reason can be found in the [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html#query-dsl-wildcard-query) : at search time, the value isn't analyzed.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for POST test-idx/doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard" : { "foo" : "QNMZ-19*" }    
  }
}

Comment: Indeed, wildcard query input is not analyzed, but this way, the search can always be performed on the lowercased value. However, I update my answer.

Comment: @ThomasC is this answer still valid for ElasticSearch 6.1? Is there any newer, more convenient feature for this kind of searching? What do you think about different kind of modeling. In example we could duplicate "foo" into "foo_lowercase" field in json which would contain "qnmz-1900". And then we could search by
curl 'localhost:9200/test-idx/doc/_search?pretty=true' -d '{"query": {"wildcard" : { "foo" : "qnmz-19*" }}
Or do you consider this kind of modeling as an antipattern for elasticsearch?

Comment: @RadosławOsiński I've not yet taken a deep look into ES 6.1. However, since ES 2.X, the `string` datatype has been replaced by text (for analyzed string) and keyword (for not_analyzed string). In my answer, `string`should be replaced by `text`in the mapping. About your suggestion, it is actually how i would implement it. Use multifield mapping to store original value in the main field, and store in subfields each analyzed version (one per analyzer). This is a good practice, the only drawback is that these fields use some space and indexing will be a bit longer. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for a good explanation, this answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked this aproach in my pet project based on ES 6.1. Data model like below allows searching as expected in question:

```
PUT test-idx
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "keylower": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": ["lowercase"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

POST /test-idx/doc/_mapping
{
    "properties": {
        "foo": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "raw": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "lowercase_foo": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "keylower"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

PUT /test-idx/doc/1
{"foo": "QNMZ-1900"}
```

Check resoults of these two searches. First will resoult one hit. Second one will return 0 hits.

```
GET /test-idx/doc/_search
{
  "query": {
     "wildcard" : { "foo.lowercase_foo" : "qnmz-19*" }
  }
}

GET /test-idx/doc/_search
{
  "query": {
     "wildcard" : { "foo" : "qnmz-19*" }
  }
}
```

Thanks @ThomasC for an opinion. Please be carefull with my answer. I am just learning Elasticsearch. I am not an expert in this database. I don't know is it production ready advice!